# I can't turn on fast renderers on Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer

When I add `Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");` as https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.4/2.4.0-pre1/ states, I get the following error: `'Forms' does not contain a definition for 'SetFlags'`. Indeed, I can't find one. So how is this meant to work? Is there another step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to upgrade `Xamarin.Forms` to the ***pre-release*** version (`2.4.0-pre1+`) in each of your projects:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.266-pre1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

[image]

After that you can set the `Forms.SetFlags`:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```